# Immediately returns to login screen after logging in

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, login, login-screen

So I just had a software update on ubuntu 14.04 and now when I try to login, it just sits there for a few seconds then returns to the login screen. I've tried restarting and doing a few things I found on the web but none of them helped. If you can, please help!

Comment: that's called login loop problem. What was the last action you did after this started happening? What's your graphics card?

Comment: What happened is i installed an update (not from like 13.04-14.04 but like bug fixes using the software update manager) it prompted me to keep or replace a file (i don't know the name) but i chose to keep it. When i restarted to complete the update it had the problem, just kept looping like what you said. also, sorry for the late response :\

Comment: And i tried the duplacate and it didn't work :(

Comment: Please answer as soon as possible, i need my computer back to do some GD for a friend :|

Comment: Anyone here?....